# My mesh doesnt follow my bone

Tags: armature, bones, parent

I have this model of a truck and I'm setting up the bone structure for a UE4 vehicle project. The armature consists of six "wheel bones" and one root bone for all other parts.

I've manage to connect all meshes to corresponding bone besides my mesh called "additional lights". When I change pose, everything follows as intended but not this mesh (additional lights).

What have I missed?

[image]

Comment: Is this mesh parented to the bones? Are the vertices assigned to the root group?

Comment: The mesh is parented to the armature. I have then selected the vertices and assigned them to the root bone.

Comment: And thanks for the reply btw.. Here is a picture of the hierarchy: https://imgur.com/xpMC6zl

Comment: Except if filtered in the image in the comment above, I think 'additional lights' should have an armature modifier (some modifier visible in the outliner tree).

Comment: THANK YOU! Once I added the armature modifier to the light they followed the root bone. I've never had to add the modifier manually, but they have appeared in some magical way... Anyway, big thanks.